# how to represent one-to-one relationship in db design?

Tags: database

Say I have two classes `Laptop` and `Lcd`. Let's now assume each Laptop can have only one `Lcd` and an `Lcd` can only be installed on one `Laptop` at any time. Let's also assume an `Lcd` can be removed from one `Laptop` and installed on another. So this is a one-to-one association from `Laptop` to `Lcd`.

Now the question is, how to design the db schema for this one-to-one relationship?

Many thanks,

Bryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to model this would be to place a foreign key in the LCD table that links back to the Laptop table. Make that column non-nullable and unique.

```
Laptop
-------------
LaptopId (PK)
...

LCD
-------------
LCDId (PK)
LaptopId (FK, Non-null, Unique constraint)
```

(It's also worth noting that this same approach would work the other way around--with the `Laptop` table having a non-nullable unique foreign key to the `LCD` table).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by having a foreign key in the Laptop table pointing to the primary key of the Lcd table. A primary key is usually an auto incremented integer and ensures that each row in a table is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a column in the `laptop` tables that references its `lcd`'s primary key *without* a join table.

You didn't specify which database software you're using, but in MySQL, this would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE laptops (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 lcd_id INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE lcds (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Would LCD_Id be a foreign key?

Comment: It could be, if you're using a version of MySQL and storage engine that support foreign keys